# Openedge 11.7 Development Studio / Eclipse - Not reading new code

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm having this sudden issue where any changes I make to the project are no longer taking effect.

I can see in the console that the new `.r file` is being made and the file explorer confirms it is being updated.

I tried running from the source code and from the rcode and completely cleaning and rebuilding the project but **nothing is changing**.

Breakpoints and going line by line in the debugging menu shows it completely skipping over the new code.

I am trying to do something as simple as changing the text of a label or trying to see a variable using an alert box but nothing works. Can't debug the new additions if the new code isn't being used.

Comment: Do you have -q in your startup parameters?

Comment: No I don't. I added it and nothing changed

Comment: My thought was that -q could, potentially, cause the problem described. Not cure it.

Comment: check which rcode is actually run, you could have an old version of the rcode in the propath

Comment: I've cleared out every single location the rcode could be running from and rebuilt the entire project, it's still not reading it.

Comment: How are you running the code? If it's a Run Configuration in PDSOE make sure the PROPATH there is correct.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but are you changing the right files? Sometimes this happens to me and I lose my mind before I realise I am changing the code in the wrong folder

Comment: 100% it's the right file, the debugger goes straight to it but ignores any changes I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be helpful, but Progress Developer Studio is a rather unstable port of Eclipse IDE. I've had some weird issues a few times (not like yours, though) where the only solution I've found was to uninstall and reinstall the entire Progress product from my computer.
I know it's annoying and time-consuming, especially when you have a lot of custom settings in your environment, but usually it solves a lot of these crazy problems. Might be worth a shot if nothing else helps.

Comment: I hate that this was the solution.